# vertically center element on the screen onsen ui

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm using [Onsen](https://onsen.io) and I'm trying to make the elements inside the `ons-page` to be vertically align center on the screen but no luck, below is what I've tried.

```
<ons-page id="login-form" modifier="full_bg">
        <ons-row align="center">
            <ons-col width="50%" vertical-align="center">
                <div style="padding-left:5px">
                    <ons-button modifier="large">Signin</ons-button>
                </div>
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col width="50%" vertical-align="center">
                <div style="padding-left:5px">
                    <ons-button modifier="large">Signin</ons-button>
                </div>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
    </ons-page>
```

Any help, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try add a  wrap it.

HTML

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <ons-row>...</ons-row>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flexbox-container {

   height: 100%;

   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -ms-flex-align: center;
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   -webkit-box-align: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Reference: https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center-flexbox